# dragablz TabablzControl wpf disable tab switch and Drag

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I am using a dragablz:TabablzControl control in WPF project and I need disable tab switch and tab drag. How can I do?

thans!

Comment: You want to do this with all tabs or specific tabs?

Comment: If this is working for you, you may accept my solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can Remove the **InterTabController**.

Thank you!

Comment: good answer @Igor , but just to know removing intertabcontroller disables detaching onlmy not reordering, but that just what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Add `FixedHeaderCount` to disable dragging

```
<dragablz:TabablzControl FixedHeaderCount="3">
```

Remove `InterTabController` to disable detaching

Comment: This should be the accepted answer to the question...